# Finding initial key of Fibonacci LFSR knowing only polynomial and output stream-cipher

Tags: stream-cipher, lfsr

I need to know whether it is possible to find the initial key of a Fibonacci LFSR knowing only length and taps and output stream-cipher bit sequence?

Plaintext is not ASCII, nor some other sort of printable characters. It's also a bit sequence.

LFSR: 15bit $X^{15}+X^{14}+1$

Comment: Is this homework (or another type of learning exercise)?

Comment: Some sort ;) But I need working solution with example